Nginx proxy through additional proxy
I have https://site1.ru and https://site2.ru . It is necessary that when applying to https://site1.ru/api the request was proxied to https://site2.ru/api and so that at the same time it remains written in the browser in the line https://site1.ru/api I need to do this via nginx. At the same time, I can't directly proxy requests from site1.ru on site2.ru. It needs to go through proxy.ru This nginx.conf was written for site1.ru
location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://proxy.ru;
        proxy_set_header Host site2.ru;
    }

But with this configuration, there is a redirect, not a proxy. Please help me, how can I make a proxy in such a situation?

What kind of redirect you've got? Maybe it is some kind of HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect? What type of proxy is proxy.ru server? Is it a forward proxy? You can check it via curl -v <request>  examining the Location response header. Such type of questions should be asked at [SF] rather than [SO].

Out-of-the-box nginx is not well-suited for forward-proxying. You can use the ngx_http_proxy_connect_module for proxying via CONNECT HTTP method or use L4 level proxying via nginx stream module (here is an in-depth article on the subject). Or alternatively you can do it using apache.
